# What is this family using?

Tags: riddle

I am 10, and I mostly use **2**, but sometimes **8**.

My older brother is 12, and he uses either **2** or **4**, depending on his mood.

My younger brother is 3, and he uses **3**.

My sister is 19, and she usually uses **4**.

My mom is 37, and she also usually uses **4**.

My dad is 40, and he uses either **4** or **6**.

My uncle is 42, and he uses either **4**, **10**, or **18**.

---

**What is this family using?**

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if the family is flavor or part of the solution. I.E., is it important who the family *is* or is it just important what they're using? Be they human or no?

Comment: @EngineerToast. Everything is a hint. There isn't much fluff or flavor in this one. They are human.

Comment: i wonder if this was inspired by the " What has 4 legs in the morning, 2 legs in the afternoon, and 3 legs at night?" riddle

Comment: @MrSudds It was not, but I just looked up that riddle, and Google had the **answer** in the browser at the top of the search results, so I guess it didn't want me to try to solve it!

Comment: I think I know what the ages mean, I just can't figure out what the other numbers refer to...

Comment: I was thinking diapers, but that'll be too rude to the family

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're referring to

> Wheels

I am 10, and I mostly use 2, but sometimes 8.

> Most of the time you use a two-wheeled bicycle, but you like to use rollerblades!

My older brother is 12, and he uses either 2 or 4, depending on his mood.

> Also your older brother uses the bike, but he likes skateboarding too!

My younger brother is 3, and he uses 3.

> Well, he is too young for a bike, better a [tricycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tricycle)

My sister is 19, and she usually uses 4.

> Your sister can drive a car!

My mom is 37, and she also usually uses 4.

> Also your mom can drive a car!

My dad is 40, and he uses either 4 or 6.

> Your dad drives too, and he is a [truck driver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six-wheel_drive).

My uncle is 42, and he uses either 4, 10, or 18.

> Also your uncle is a truck driver, a [HUGE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-trailer_truck) truck driver!

Comment: was just about to post the same!

Comment: Nice job. The uncle drives either a car, the tractor part of a tractor-trailer (10 wheels), or the entire semi truck (18 wheels). For the 6, I was thinking a dually truck.

Comment: @JLee Where are you from? I've very rarely seen lorries with more than 12 wheels. PS. Great puzzle and great answer!

Comment: @randal'thor I am from the USA and I live in Atlanta, Georgia. Semi trucks, also called 18 wheelers, have 18 wheels. The Tractor part has 10 wheels, and the trailer part has 8 wheels. I have never heard the word lorries. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-trailer_truck

Comment: @JLee "Lorry" is British English for "truck".

Comment: @randal'thor I just learned something new. Amazing how many linguistic/word differences a large pond can cause!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is:

> **Shoes**
>
>  Each family member can have a different number of pairs of shoes (running, indoor, sports, sandals, etc.), although this might be a lot of shoes for the uncle.
>
> Alternatively it could be the number of shoes each has, and the 3 year old has 3 shoes because he is a silly young child.

Comment: lol @ "the 3 year old has 3 shoes because he is a silly young child."

Comment: Something is weird with the world the day that your mom and sister have only 4 pair of shoes, and your uncle has 18! But I didn't down-vote you, mostly because I don't down-vote, unless it's an extreme case.

Comment: I'll try to think of a better answer, just need to find my thinking shoes ;)